# PIC12F629 Doesn't react on input

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplabx

I've build this circuit :

- The diode is actually a LED.

[image]

With this code on MPLAB x,XC8 :

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#pragma config WDTE=OFF , BOREN=OFF , PWRTE=ON , MCLRE=OFF , FOSC=INTRCIO

void main(){
TRISIO = 0x001000;
GPIO = 0b000000;
    while(GPIO = 0b001000){
        GPIO = 0b110111;
    }

}
```

But the GP0(pin7) doesn't react on GP3(pin7) pressed button, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a pull down resistor to your button.
[image]
The GPIO pins are sensitive to voltages. When you press the button, the voltage (vs GND) at the GPIO is set to 5V, and the MCU will see this. But when you release the button, what is the voltage at the GPIO? 0V? probabliy not, what forces that voltage to be 0V?

When left open, or floating, the value of the GPIO is undefined. It could be 1, or 0. Or could switch quickly (oscillate). On AT Tiny, when left open under some condition the input stage starts to consume a lot of current... (which is bad for a low power MCU...)

Thus, you could solve this by adding a resistor (called a "pull down") between your GPIO and GND (10k is fine).

Or you may connect your button to GND instead of 5V and enable the internal pull up resistor of the MCU GPIO (I don't know if this particular model offers that feature).

Comment: I put one 16k resistor between key, but when my hand get near to key PIC act like i press the button!it does not really react on my button.it lite the led for a while and then it turn it off.

Comment: Where did you put the resistor exactly? It's not across the button but across the GPIO pin and GND. Your observed behavior is exactly what happens when an input is left floating.

Comment: I update the circuit picture.

Comment: Ok, This is not where you have to put the resistor. You should connect your resistor between the P4 pin of your micro and the minus (-) port of your 5V source.

Answer (score 4):

In the following code a single equals sign is an assignment operator so it will be trying to set the GPIO value. It should be like this for a comparison:

```
while(GPIO == 0b001000){
    GPIO = 0b110111;
}
```

However you're doing an exact comparison so all other bits must be zero for it to match, what you probably really want is something like this that includes a bitwise-AND to just check a single bit:

```
while(GPIO & 0b001000){
    GPIO = 0b110111;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how the compiler xc8 is so relax about program syntax errors.

Comment: Thank's sir, i understand what you mean but how i can tell it to compare only fourth bit of GPIO with Zero?could i use 0bxx1xxx?

Comment: @user38322, that's not really a syntax error, sometimes assigning in an if statement can be helpful, some compilers would give you an error. The only the fourth bit is because of that value near the `&` - you might want to spend a bit of time learning about bitwise operators they can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Also take note of Blup1980's answer - I didn't spot that but you will want a pull-down resistor as well.

Comment: If you make a habit of putting the constant value on the left it will be an invalid expression (generating an error) if you use = instead of ==.

Comment: That's a clever trick! @user38322 While you probably don't need the `==` this time Spehro is saying if you were in the habit of putting `0b001000 == GPIO` then you'd get an error if you missed the second equals sign. Also just noticed an error in an earlier comment - I meant to say some compilers will generate a warning if you use a single one, not an error because it's valid C code.

Comment: I read about bit wise operation but what is the result of it true or false ? how can i say 0001100 is true or false ? and why when i put my hand near switch, LEDs turn on ?

Comment: @user38322, in an if statement anything that's not zero is true. So by anding the bits together with you'll only get something true when one or more of the bits match between the port and what you're trying to compare against. So your 0001100 would be checking if either ports 2 & 3 were high, 0000100 would just be port 2 (remembering they start at bit zero).